# How to convert a dictionary list to JSON

Tags: python, json, django, pandas, machine-learning

I'm trying to peform an A/B test of two ML models and I require to parse data to the model via json.  Below is the code

```
for i in range(100):
    input_data = dict(X_test.iloc[i])
    target = y_test.iloc[i]
    r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/ddos_classifier/predict?status=ab_testing", input_data)
    response = r.json()
    # provide feedback
    requests.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/mlrequests/{}".format(response["request_id"]), {"feedback": target})
```

input_data is in the form of a dictionary
The code returns this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Full traceback

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-254afd81a7cc> in <module>
      3     target = y_test.iloc[i]
      4     r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/ddos_classifier/predict?status=ab_testing", input_data)
----> 5     response = r.json()
      6     # provide feedback
      7     requests.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/mlrequests/{}".format(response["request_id"]), {"feedback": target})

c:\users\mark silla\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    896                     # used.
    897                     pass
--> 898         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    899 
    900     @property

c:\users\mark silla\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

c:\users\mark silla\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

c:\users\mark silla\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What could be the issue

Comment: So, do you have *any* ideas about how to turn a `dict` into `json`?

Comment: Post the full traceback. Right now, it is unclear which line of your code is raising the error. If I had to guess, it would be the line `response = r.json()`. If so, I suggest `print(r.content)` to see what it is that you are getting back. Perhaps also do `print(r.status_code, r.reason)`.

Comment: r.status/ r.reason brings up and Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
input_data = json.dumps(dict(X_test.iloc[i]))
```

then post `input_data`